# Is there any value in Python for which isinstance(value, object) is not True?

Tags: python, python-2.x, isinstance

It is my understanding that since type/class unification *every* value is of a type that derives from `object`. However I can't find absolute confirmation of this in the docs. While it stands to reason that `isinstance(anything, object)` should always be `True`, I could also imagine there being legacy edge cases in the Python 2 codebase. Does anyone know of an example where `isinstance(value, object)` is *not* `True`?

Context: as part of a type hierarchy I'm designing, there's an all-encompasing `Alpha` type for which I want `isinstance(obj, Alpha)` to always return `True`. I'm thinking that on Python 2.6+ `ABCMeta.register(object)` should do the trick, but I want to be sure.

EDIT: For posterity's sake, `ABCMeta.register(object)` will not work (try it). Ethan Furman provides an alternative solution for this case in his answer below.

Comment: Everything is an instance of `object`. There is trickery at the C-level to make even `type(object)` an instance of object. I don't have a reference right now but there was a blog post out there sometime in the last six months about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create classes in non-Python code (`C`, for example) that do not derive from `object`.

You should be able to achieve what you want by adding `__subclasshook__` to your `Alpha`:

```
--> import abc
--> class Test(object):
...   __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
...   @classmethod
...   def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
...     return True
...
--> isinstance(dict(), Test)
True
--> isinstance(42, Test)
True
--> isinstance(0.59, Test)
True
--> class old_style:
...     pass
...
--> isinstance(old_style(), Test)
True
```

Comment: Hrm.. but any pure-python type will always derive from object? That might be good enough, as long as its also true of commonly used/standard library C modules (cStringIO, cDecimal, etc.)

Comment: Unless they are still using the old style classes -- but if that distinction is not important your `__subclasshook__` can ignore it (as the example does).

Comment: Awesome! That looks like the ideal solution for `Alpha`. Thanks Ethan!

Answer (score 0):

In 2.x, user-defined classes (and a few stdlib classes) do not derive from object by default. This is fixed in 3.x.

Comment: Mayby that's what maaku meant by "since type/class unification"?

Comment: @WolframH: every *literal* is an instance of object. It is still (in 2.x) possible to create classes whose instances are not instances of object.